# Polyxpoly returns empty matrix

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry

I'm writing a code in which I have to use polyxpoly and I'm having some issues with the output.

My code:

```
x=[-286.1018 -363.2334];
y=[4617.4 4725.1];
xv=[-316.7 -128-9 -268.3 -1864.6 -840.4];
yv=[4694.4 4944.7 5641.7 6002.0 4519.9];
[xi,yi] = polyxpoly(x,y,xv,yv);
```

And it returns:

```
Empty matrix: 0-by-2
```

What am I doing wrong I can't understand why it is not working (it should return the intersection points)? Can someone help me? Is this a bug of the function polyxpoly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an empty matrix because the polylines defined for `(x,y)` and `(xv,yv)` don't intersect. This can clearly be shown by the plotting the polylines:

```
x=[-286.1018 -363.2334];
y=[4617.4 4725.1];
xv=[-316.7 -128-9 -268.3 -1864.6 -840.4];
yv=[4694.4 4944.7 5641.7 6002.0 4519.9];
mapshow(xv, yv);
mapshow(x,y,'color','red')
```

We get:

[image]

As you can see, the bigger shape defined by `xv` and `yv` is **not** closed, so the smaller line defined by `x` and `y` never intersect the shape.  If you want to find the intersection points, you'll need to **close** the larger polygon.  This can simply be done by duplicating the **first** `xv` and `yv` point in the array and making sure these appear **at the end** of the `xv` and `yv` arrays so that you close the polygon:

```
x=[-286.1018 -363.2334];
y=[4617.4 4725.1];
xv=[-316.7 -128-9 -268.3 -1864.6 -840.4];
yv=[4694.4 4944.7 5641.7 6002.0 4519.9];
%// Change
xv = [xv xv(1)];
yv = [yv yv(1)];
mapshow(xv, yv);
mapshow(x,y,'color','red')
```

We get:

[image]

That's better!  Now try `polyxpoly` on the new `xv` and `yv` values:

```
>> [xi,yi] = polyxpoly(x, y, xv, yv)

xi =

 -336.5178


yi =

   4.6878e+03
```

We can show this point of intersection by adding one more `mapshow` call to the already spawned figure:

```
mapshow(xi,yi,'DisplayType','point','Marker','o')
```

We get:

[image]

You can see that the point of intersection has been found, and that it is delineated by a red circle in the map.

Comment: Wow thanks so much sir! I got it now!! Thanks for the complete answer. @rayryeng

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!